# Loop through list of products and output onto different spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook (C:\DOORS.xlsx) with the following data:

```
 A           B            C               D
100 ...    Type A     Description      Remarks
102 ...    Type B     Description      Remarks
103 ...    Type C     Description      Remarks
```

I need to create a loop that goes thru each row that outputs the data onto a different workbook (C:\QT.xlsx). It needs to be able to make sure the values for Door and Description cannot be more than 55 characters long. If they are more than 55 characters in length then it needs to move the remainder onto the next row without cutting a word in half. Also if Remarks is blank then this is where the description should go.

Output would look like this on QT.xlsx:

```
'Starting at cell D18

          A    B    C       D
  18                       Door: 100, 100, 103, 104, 105,
  19                       106, 107, 108, 110, 107
  20                       Type A
  21                       Remarks A 'Text Should Be Bold
  22                       This is a really long description
  23                       and needs to fit in this space by
  24                       being 55 characters long and does 
  25                       cut a word in half.
  26                       
  27                       Door: 102, 100, 103, 104,
  28                       Type B
  29                       Remarks B 'Text Should Be Bold
  30                       Description
  31                       
  32                       Door: 103, 100, 103, 104,
  33                       Type C
  34                       Description 'This is a blank cell in DOORS.xlsx
  35
```

I'm still learning VBA and I'm new to looping. Not sure where to start but any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats a lot of stuff you want to put in vba... better do it step by step... try to do just one item... then make a loop... then add other item and do the formating/cutting or whatever as the last step... first try to find something to start with...

Comment: Would this be better to do in python? Or a different language? @Dirk Thanks for the advice ill see what i can come up with.

Comment: @Dirk Reichel Where should I start? I've been brain storming and was thinking i would break my final description into parts, combine, and then transfer.  I was thinking i would start with the numbers and check there length. Break the strings up if their longer than 55 characters. Do the Same with the Description and then combine how i wanted them above.From there i can just copy and paste them over to the workbook i want them in. Does this sound like a good approach?

Comment: hmm... at first you need a WB with macros (asuming you will do it in VBA) (*.xlsx dont have them)... so to simply start and build something up, we will store the data here (and put it into the other workbook later)... I'll create an answer which we will change till we get it to what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** This should work as you need it. However, it is a huge change, if there are questions, just write a comment. :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetTheData()
  Dim MyWSSource As Worksheet
  Dim MyWSTarget As Worksheet
  Dim sArr As Variant
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Byte, iLines As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'will automatically set to true after the sub ends

  Set MyWSSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\DOORS.xlsx").Sheets(1) 'set your source wb+sheet
  Set MyWSTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\QT.xlsx").Sheets(1)    'set your target wb+sheet
  iLines = MyWSSource.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row     'get the last line to be processed
  j = 18                                                     'set the first line to output

  For i = 1 To iLines
    For k = 1 To 4
      If Len(MyWSSource.Cells(i, Array(1, 2, 4, 3)(k - 1)).Value) Then 'if cell is empty it will be skipped
        If k = 1 Then
          ' ---------- new lines start ----------
          MyWSTarget.Cells(j, 2).Value = Len(MyWSSource.Cells(i, 1).Value) - Len(Replace(MyWSSource.Cells(i, 1).Value, ",", "")) + 1 'new line for count in b
          If Left(MyWSSource.Cells(i, 3).Value, 4) = "Pair" Then 'case sensitive
          'If LCase(Left(MyWSSource.Cells(i, 3).Value, 4)) = "pair" Then 'not case sensitive
            MyWSTarget.Cells(j, 3).Value = "PR"
          Else
            MyWSTarget.Cells(j, 3).Value = "EA"
          End If
          ' ---------- new lines end ----------
          sArr = CropText("Door: " & MyWSSource.Cells(i, 1).Value) 'sets the "Door: " for column A
        Else
          sArr = CropText(MyWSSource.Cells(i, Array(1, 2, 4, 3)(k - 1)).Value)
          'the "Array(1, 2, 4, 3)(k - 1)" switches col C and D cus you want A->B->D->C
        End If

        If k = 3 Then MyWSTarget.Cells(j, 4).Font.Bold = True   'bolt Remark-line
        MyWSTarget.Cells(j, 4).Value = sArr(0): j = j + 1       'input text and goto next line

        While Len(sArr(1))
          sArr = CropText(CStr(sArr(1)))
          If k = 3 Then MyWSTarget.Cells(j, 4).Font.Bold = True 'bolt Remark-line
          MyWSTarget.Cells(j, 4).Value = sArr(0): j = j + 1     'input text and goto next line
        Wend
      End If
    Next
    j = j + 1 'adds an empty line after each dataset
  Next

  MyWSSource.Parent.Close 0 'close your source (discard changes -> no changes made)
  MyWSTarget.Parent.Close 1 'close your target (save changes)
End Sub

Public Function CropText(a As String) As Variant
  Dim b As String, i As Long
  If Len(a) > 55 Then
    For i = 0 To 55
      If Mid(a, 56 - i, 1) = " " Then
        CropText = Array(Left(a, 55 - i), Mid(a, 57 - i))
        Exit Function
      End If
    Next
    CropText = Array(Left(a, 55), Mid(a, 56)) 'new line -> see *NOTE
  Else
   CropText = Array(a, "")
  End If
End Function
```

`CropText(string)` will split the text into 2 parts (the first is shorter than 56 characters and the second will be all thats left) ***NOTE**: If the text string has more than 55 characters without a space, it will be cut at the 55th character!

How it looks for me: (without the column B/C change)

Input: (DOORS.xlsx)
[image]

Output: (QT.xlsx)
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Dirk Reichel, I have a work book called Door Program.xlsm with a userform with a few buttons that i use to do different things. I added your code to one of the buttons. If im reading the code above correct then what it does is open my DOORS.xlsx file and it reads each line in column A and adds Door: in front of it. It then calls the CropText function to split the text into 2 parts. What does this line do? .Cells(18 + j, 4).Value = sArr(0)

Comment: It simply adds the first part of the string to the cell in column "D" starting with row 18 (right now to your macro-workbook, but later to the desired workbook)

Comment: Sweet! I feel like i can read code pretty good but when it comes to writing it im still learning. Its kinda like i have writers block haha. So for the next part would it be a new For statement or would we incorporate it in to the one we have. We use this to identify what were gonna look thru iLines2 = MyWB.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row. I changed it to 2 cause thats gonna look thru column 2? Thanks SO MUCH for helping me with this btw!

Comment: its not necessary... we just include the output for column 2 to 4 in the existing loop (i'll change the code a lilbit later)

Comment: if i'm correct, you want Column A -> B -> D -> C (and if any of them is empty, skip it). Am I right?

Comment: Yup thats what i need to do

Comment: Just saw the code above. I will go thru and check it out. Thank you so much again!

Comment: Would it be difficult to add 2 more things to this loop? I would like to insert data into the first line column B and C next to where it puts the door numbers. In column B i would like it to count the commas +1 from cloumn A of the input file and paste it in column B. Column C i would like it to be equal to EA unless the first word in Description is Pair. Then it should be equal to PR. Ill post an example . I'm gonna try and figure it out, but any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a good resources to learn more about loops? I feel if i had a bunch of examples i would be able to pick up on it better. Also

Comment: added it. choose 1 of the 2 new `If ...` lines (while the first line is case sensitive ("pAir" will not count), the second one is not). to use the second line simply remove the `'` from it and add one to the first. regarding the help with loops: all i ever used was the MS-Office-Help. was more like "learning by doing"... whenever there was repeating code i tried to do it with a loop. however, there are a LOT of good examples at this side... still the best way to understand is by just using the functions :)

Comment: Thanks Dirk! I tried running it and it works but it prints out the total commas and EA or PR three times.(See Picture Below), I think the line right after new line start does the counting but im not sure what tells it where it goes. I just need it to print only the first one for each dataset.

Comment: oh sorry... was in the wrong line (the new lines start after `If k = 1 Then`... my fault. changed it... however, the count itself was correct: in your picture -> 1st and 2nd item (no comma) = 1, 3rd item (3 commas) = 4... you asked for count of commas +1... did i got you wrong?

Comment: Yes count is correct. If there are no commas then it's value is just one. Thank You Sooo Much!

Comment: Hey i was doing a little studying and i had a question about a couple parts. Array(1, 2, 4, 3)(k - 1)).Value what does it mean? Is this defining the column in my input sheet? Does this,  Len(MyWSSource.Cells(i, Array(1, 2, 4, 3)(k - 1)).Value), skip the blank row because it reads a value in that range? If it doesnt read anything, it then skips it?

Comment: @geoff yes and yes... it simply switches column 3 and 4... the `Len` checks for the length of a string. If you do it correct you need to use `If Len (...) > 0 Then` to only act if there is text. However, using a number for `True/False` 0 will count as `False` (all other numbers are `True`) so I simply skipped the `> 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
    A    B    C                      D
18       10    EA        Door: 100, 100, 103, 104, 105,
19                       106, 107, 108, 110, 107
20                       Type A
21                       Remarks A 'Text Should Be Bold
22                       This is a really long description
23                       and needs to fit in this space by
24                       being 55 characters long and does 
25                       cut a word in half.
26                       
27        4    PR        Door: 102, 100, 103, 104
28                       Type B
29                       Remarks B 'Text Should Be Bold
30                       PAIR Description
31                       
32        3    EA        Door: 103, 100, 103, 104
33                       Type C
34                       Description 'This is a blank cell in DOORS.xlsx
35
```

[image]